# React Multistep form with single child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent form component and a child form component. It's a multistep form where each step is a rendering of the same child component. The child component's input fields change dynamically based on the user's input. It works and I can successfully pass the input up to the state of the parent form component, but the problem is that the inputs persist to the next step.

I'm assuming this is because each step uses the same component, but I don't know how to avoid this behavior without an excessive amount of state usage to load the appropriate values for whichever step the user is at. I can clear the form as the user moves to each next step, but then the user wouldn't be able to go back to a previous step.

Any suggestions?

(I know I could just shove everything into one component or make a separate component for each step, but neither of those seem like the most efficient approach)

Comment: Can you please provide some source code for us to be able to look at and give you accurate advice on the solution.  My best guess is you need to reset your input state values but that's just a best guess based on what you have provided.

Comment: Please post some source code, this would really help the answering process. You might be able to add a ref to your form and do `refName.current.reset()`?